# Nodejs password reset I get an emai and click on the link but the new password does not change. I can only log in with old password

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am 99% done with my password reset application.  I get an email for the password reset, but my new password change does not change in my mongodb.  I can't log in with new password only old password.  What am I doing wrong

router.post('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {

```
    async.waterfall([
      function(done) {
        
        Account.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
          if (!user) {
            req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
            return res.redirect('back');
          }

       

          user.password = req.body.password;
          //user.password = hashedPassword;
          user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
          user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;
          
          user.save(function(err) {
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
              done(err, user);
            
            });
          });
        });

      
      },
      function(user, done) {
        
            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'Gmail',
            auth:{
               
                    user: '',
                    pass: ''
               
                }
            });
       
        var mailOptions = {
          to: user.email,
          from: '',
          subject: 'Your password has been changed',
          text: 'Hello,\n\n' +
            'This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + user.email + ' has just been changed.\n'
        };
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
          req.flash('success', 'Success! Your password has been changed.');
          done(err);
        });
      }
    ], function(err) {
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
```

Comment: I figured it out. I had to user setPassword function

if(req.body.password === req.body.confirm) { user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err) {

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had to user setPassword function

if(req.body.password === req.body.confirm) {
user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err) {

Thanks.